# Java : How to count lines from TB size file in faster way

Tags: java

Our file is going to be of 10 tb on an avg in size. Was wondering if there is a better way of doing than this to make it faster?

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
int lines = 0;
while (reader.readLine() != null) lines++;
reader.close();
```

Comment: 100tb, did you mean 100gb? Why are you creating such large files? If it is 100tb then I would first refactor the code that is creating such large files.

Comment: @Ros5292 : Will that be faster? Will that be able to handle file size like ours?

Comment: Divide and conquer pattern? Two threads, one starts at the end and one at the beginning.. Can't help you on how to implement it though.

Comment: @Patty you correct, it won't be faster rather it will exhaust the memory. I should delete my comment. Thanks !!

Comment: Why? Why do you need to know how many lines there are, without processing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think anyone can really answer your question as asked. Here are the missing details that I would need to really give you a good answer.

1. What file system are you using to store 10TB files? 
   If they are really 10TB then I am assuming you are running a cluster of some sort. What distributed file system are you using?
2. What OS are you running on? 
   Linux/Win/etc.
3. Do you have to use Java or can you dive down into C/C++?
   Handling files this large really really fast will require hooking into system calls that are not portable
4. Can you write out the number of lines when you are creating the file? 
   This problem goes away if you just write the number of lines when you are creating it.
5. If this is on a cluster are you coping the file locally and then processing?
6. Are you mapping/mounting a drive over the network and processing? If so then you are limited by the network bandwith to move a 10TB file from your cluster to your workstation

Without those 6 items anyone is just guessing.

---

Update with OP response:

Here is what I would do given the info.

1. Before you do anything at all you need to see if you are saturating your network connection. Given you are dealing with HUGE amounts of data over the network there may be nothing you can do beyond upgrading your switches and tuning your network stack on your servers. If, and only if, you have confirmed that your network connection(s) are not pegged at 100% below are other things I would try.
2. Start simple and increase the buffer size on your [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader-java.io.Reader-int-) I think that java defaults to 8192 for the buffer size. Depending on how you have the HDFS file system setup and your network you may be able to get substantial speedups by just increasing the buffer size.
3. If you're still slow I would try to use a [File channel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html)
4. Still slow? Run two threads one from the start of the file and one from the end. Play with the buffer sizes like you did in step 2.
5. If you're still too slow can you hook right into HDFS? If you are reading a file over an NFS mount hooking directly into HDFS may give a performance boost.
6. Still slow?? Install another network card and channel bond it to double your throughput and then start back at step 1 :)

Good luck!!

Comment: To ans your question: 1> It's a java multi threaded process that's creating the file and writing it into HDFS file system. 2> Linux operating system. 3> Java  4> Yes we are doing that. However, it's part of the validation process that requires this use case 5> We are directly writing in HDFS (segmented) 6> Drive is mounted over the network